# Select within Where Clause returns no data

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm trying to use this Select within a Where Clause:

```
select s.machine 
from gv$session s 
where s.sid = (select  to_number(sys_context('USERENV','SID')) SID 
               from dual)
```

when I execute it alone it returns `'DHAS\TI07'`, but within the where clause

```
SELECT reg.MAQUINA 
FROM REG_MAQUINA reg 
WHERE to_char('DHAS\'||reg.MAQUINA) = (select s.machine 
                                       from gv$session s 
                                       where s.sid = (select  to_number(sys_context('USERENV','SID')) SID 
                                                      from dual))
```

doesn't bring any rows, the thing is that if I replace the select with the hard coded result `'DHAS\TI07'`  on the second query, it works

Comment: `s.sid = (select  to_number(sys_context('USERENV','SID')) SID 
               from dual)` can be simplified to `s.sid = to_number(sys_context('USERENV','SID')`

Comment: tried:
 DECLARE
v_maq VARCHAR2(64);
v_qam VARCHAR2(64);
Begin
       --QUERY 1
          select s.machine INTO v_maq
    from gv$session s 
    where s.sid = to_number(sys_context('USERENV','SID'))
    AND ROWNUM = 1;
       --Gives output - 'FEDL01'
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_maq);    
--END;
      --QUERY 2
       SELECT   UNIQUE reg.MAQUINA INTO v_qam   
    FROM   DBAMV.REG_MAQUINA reg 
    WHERE  to_char('DHAS\'||reg.MAQUINA) = v_maq;   
      
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_qam);    
END;
---------------
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 14

Comment: Do **not** put code in comments. **[edit]** your question

Comment: I suspect space character coming back from the inner select.  Try:  select '>'||s.machine||'<' 
from gv$session s 
where s.sid = (select  to_number(sys_context('USERENV','SID')) SID 
               from dual)
               ;

Answer (score 0):

The `machine` in `GV$SESSION` returns - The operating system name for the client machine. This may include the domain name if present.

So when I tried to execute it from SQL Developer and from SQLPlus from the same machine, It gave me a different result.

```
-- Query

SELECT
    S.MACHINE
FROM
    GV$SESSION S
WHERE
    S.SID = (
        SELECT
            TO_NUMBER(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SID')) SID
        FROM
            DUAL
    );

-- Result in SQL Developer
-- domain name not present
MACHINE                                                         
----------------------------------------------------------------
ATPL-LAP-18



-- Result in SQLPlus
-- domain name present
MACHINE
----------------------------------------------------------------
WORKGROUP\ATPL-LAP-18
```

Ultimately you need to remove Domain name of the machine from the Machine column of the GV$SESSION as you are storing the only machine name in your table `REG_MAQUINA`. Then you can use this query with any tool.

You can try this query:

```
SELECT
    REG.MAQUINA
FROM
    REG_MAQUINA REG
WHERE
    TO_CHAR(REG.MAQUINA) = (
        SELECT
            REPLACE(S.MACHINE,'DHAS\','')
        FROM
            GV$SESSION S
        WHERE
            S.SID = (
                SELECT
                    TO_NUMBER(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SID')) SID
                FROM
                    DUAL
            )
    );
```

Cheers!!

Comment: The `select ... from dual` is completely useless (as in the original query)

Comment: Yes, @a_horse_with_no_name, I totally understand it. But, I didn't want to change the original query. I have seen your comment on question also and You are perfectly right.

Comment: thanks for the patience, tried this last one, but still no results

Comment: I also did the ">'||s.machine||'<' " and noticed that "<" isn't showing, but I don't know why